# Php to database outputs code in browser

Tags: php, mamp

I am following a tutorial on w3schools. I have a database and I am trying to add some information to a table. Here is the code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "sample";
$password = "";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

When I load it on my browser using a localhost it outputs the code exactly as it is written above. I have tried a few fixes such as adding the line AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php in the httpd.conf file. I also uncommented the line LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so. Any suggestions?

Ok so I tried switching from "file://Users/Adrian/Sites/test.php" to "http://localhost:8888/Users/Adrian/Sites/test.php" and it returns a 404 not found on the server.

I figured out what I was doing wrong. Originally I had a folder in my Library/Webserver/Documents. When I would load html files it would work fine but when I loaded php files it would output the source code. The **solution** I found is to put the files in the htdocs folder with MAMP. Now everything is working as it is supposed to be. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is your file executed by a server? Is it a .php file?

Comment: This has to be executed on a computer with `PHP` installed on. Is it?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the good filetype (.php)?

Comment: Which is the location of your script? Provide us the url you are using to run your script.

Comment: The local url I am using is this: file:///Users/Adrian/Sites/test.php